# Improving NetChain for Physical Data

Tags: physics, neural-networks

I am trying to **improve** my `NetChain` to better predict physical data from the industrial standard for water/steam [published by the IAPWS](http://www.iapws.org/relguide/IF97-Rev.pdf).

Basically, this industrial standard divides the pressure-temperature plane into different zones.  Through different empirical fits in different zones, thermodynamic data is interpolated.  I have outlined by working example below.

Using Mathematica's `Predict[]` function and the `GradientBoostedTrees` method, I was able to create a prediction object that matches this industrial data quite well (most prediction is within 10-15%).  I chose 95% of the data to train my `Predict[]` object.  Empirically, I find that anything less than 95% of more than 95% has larger error (due to overfitting or underfitting probably).

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dnaneet/ML/master/se/data.dat";
datasetDirty = Import[url, "Data"]; (*has some "0" regions that need removal*)
(*names={'celcius','bar','region','kJPerKg'}*)
dataset = 
 Select[datasetDirty, #[[3]] != 
    0 &]; (*Select only those rows and columns with non zero region*)
s = Dimensions[dataset][[1]];

T = dataset[[2 ;; s, 1]]; (*temperature, C*)    
P = dataset[[2 ;; s, 2]]; (*pressure, bar*)    
r = dataset[[2 ;; s, 3]] /. {0 -> "r0", 1 -> "r1", 2 -> "r2", 
    3 -> "r3", 4 -> "r4", 5 -> "r5"}; (*region, class/label*)    
h = dataset[[2 ;; s, 4]]; (*enthalpy*)

SeedRandom[123];
thermoState = Thread[{T, P}]; (*thermodynamic state*)
mldata = 
 RandomSample[Thread[thermoState -> h]]; s = Dimensions[mldata][[1]];
training = 
 mldata[[1 ;; Ceiling[0.95*s]]]; (*90%-10% works best*)
validation = 
 mldata[[Ceiling[0.95*s] + 1 ;; s]];

pThermo1 = Predict[training, Method -> "GradientBoostedTrees"] (*takes about 1 minute and consumes about 3GB RAM*)
```

I then created a Neural Network object that does the same thing.  The `NetChain` contains layers that were arrived at by trial and error.

```
(*Putting data into proper format for NN*)
mldata2 = Table[mldata[[i, 1]] -> {mldata[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, s, 1}];
training2 = mldata2[[1 ;; Ceiling[0.95 s] ;; All]];

net = NetChain[{
   128, Tanh, 32, 8, 1},
  "Input" -> 2]
NNThermo1 = NetTrain[net, training2]
```

The percentage error between ground truth (actual data, `mldata` object) and the predict object (`pThermo1`), ground truth (`mldata` object) and the NN object (`NNThermo1`) is found.  The NN prediction is *not as good* as that from `Predict`.  I can tell that the NN can be improved by tweaking the layers.

```
errorTbl = Table[
  {
   (mldata[[i, 2]] - pThermo1[mldata[[i]][[1]]])*100/mldata[[i, 2]],
   First[(mldata[[i, 2]] - NNThermo1[mldata[[i]][[1]]])*100/
      mldata[[i, 2]]]
   }, {i, 1, s, 1000}]


ListLogPlot[Abs[{errorTbl[[All, 1]], errorTbl[[All, 2]]}], 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"", "%Error"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"From Predict[]", "From NetTrain[]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "%Error"]
```

[image]

I have watched through the Neural Network videos on Wolfram U and based on that found that a combination of `DotPlus[]` and `Tanh[]` layers as used in my example above, leads to the result I have.

Is there some data transformation or different layering (or a combination) that might help?  I am not a data-scientist but am a mechanical engineer with relatively new experience in this field of neural networks.  It is fascinating that Mathematica allows me to work so swiftly with NNs.  I just wish to make my NN prediction better `:)`

### Some more info

The (T,P,h) data clusters in interesting fashion:

```
subset1 = Thread[{T, h}];
c1 = FindClusters[subset1, 4];
ListPlot[c1, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Temperature [C]", "Specific Enthalpy [kJ/kg]"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> 0.012}]
```

[image]

```
subset2 = Thread[{P, h}];
c2 = FindClusters[subset2, 4];
ListPlot[c2, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Pressure [bar]", "Specific Enthalpy [kJ/kg]"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> 0.012}]
```

[image]

Comment: Recently i'm trying to create a neural net to predict solar radiation and for my input data, the Ramp function is more efficient that Tanh.

Comment: @ErickSabino  Efficient as in accurate or faster?  Thanks for the input!